# I have error in fav.icon file during website deployment to localhost

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, ejs

I have an error below when i open mozilla developer tool:

[image]

Right now this error is stopping me from implement my own css style. I am using EJS to make this website. Here is how my backend looks like:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const ejs = require('ejs');
//Step 1
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const _ = require('lodash');

const homeContent = "Lacus vel facilisis volutpat est velit egestas dui id ornare. Semper auctor neque vitae tempus quam. Sit amet cursus sit amet dictum sit amet justo. Viverra tellus in hac habitasse. Imperdiet proin fermentum leo vel orci porta. Donec ultrices tincidunt arcu non sodales neque sodales ut. Mattis molestie a iaculis at erat pellentesque adipiscing. Magnis dis parturient montes nascetur ridiculus mus mauris vitae ultricies. Adipiscing elit ut aliquam purus sit amet luctus venenatis lectus. Ultrices vitae auctor eu augue ut lectus arcu bibendum at. Odio euismod lacinia at quis risus sed vulputate odio ut. Cursus mattis molestie a iaculis at erat pellentesque adipiscing.";
const aboutContent = "Hac habitasse platea dictumst vestibulum rhoncus est pellentesque. Dictumst vestibulum rhoncus est pellentesque elit ullamcorper. Non diam phasellus vestibulum lorem sed. Platea dictumst quisque sagittis purus sit. Egestas sed sed risus pretium quam vulputate dignissim suspendisse. Mauris in aliquam sem fringilla. Semper risus in hendrerit gravida rutrum quisque non tellus orci. Amet massa vitae tortor condimentum lacinia quis vel eros. Enim ut tellus elementum sagittis vitae. Mauris ultrices eros in cursus turpis massa tincidunt dui.";
const contactContent = "Scelerisque eleifend donec pretium vulputate sapien. Rhoncus urna neque viverra justo nec ultrices. Arcu dui vivamus arcu felis bibendum. Consectetur adipiscing elit duis tristique. Risus viverra adipiscing at in tellus integer feugiat. Sapien nec sagittis aliquam malesuada bibendum arcu vitae. Consequat interdum varius sit amet mattis. Iaculis nunc sed augue lacus. Interdum posuere lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit. Pulvinar elementum integer enim neque. Ultrices gravida dictum fusce ut placerat orci nulla. Mauris in aliquam sem fringilla ut morbi tincidunt. Tortor posuere ac ut consequat semper viverra nam libero.";

const app = express();

//Step 3
const postSchema = {
  title: String,
  bodyContent: String
};
//Step 4
const Post = mongoose.model('Post', postSchema);

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static("public"));

//Step 2
//The localhost is by default
mongoose.connect('Your own mongodb database', {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true});

app.get("/", function(req,res){
  //Step 7
  Post.find({}, function(err, posts){
    res.render('home', {
      homeContent: homeContent,
      posts: posts
    });
  });
});

app.get('/about', function(req,res){
  res.render('about', {aboutContent: aboutContent});
});

app.get('/contact', function(req,res){
  res.render('contact', {contactContent: contactContent});
});

app.get('/compose', function(req,res){
  res.render('compose');
});

app.get('/post/:postId', function(req,res){
  const urlDataParam = req.params.postId;

  //Step 8
  Post.findOne({_id: urlDataParam}, function(err, post){
    res.render('post', {
      title: post.title,
      content: post.bodyContent
    });
  });
});

app.post('/compose', function(req,res){
  //Step 5
  const post = Post({
    title: req.body.postTitle,
    bodyContent: req.body.postBody
  });
  //Step 6
  post.save(function(err){
    if(err){
      return console.log(err);
    }else{
      res.redirect('/');
    }
  });
});

app.listen(1000, function(){
 console.log('The server is starting at port 1000');
});
```

and here is how my file structure looks like:

[image]

I am using boostrap in my header file like below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Daily Blog</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
</head>

  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <p class="navbar-brand">DAILY BLOG</p>
        </div>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <!-- 6 -->
            <li id="home"><a href="/">HOME</a></li>
            <li id="about"><a href="/about">ABOUT US</a></li>
            <li id="contact"><a href="/contact">CONTACT US</a></li>
          </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
```

Any help would be appreciate.

Comment: _"this error is stopping me from implement my own css style"_... that's extremely unlikely

Comment: Then why i cannot implement my on css style? I have already make a public directory and follow all the example that is available but i still cannot implement the css style

Comment: Use your browser's dev tools to check what's going on with your CSS. Make sure it loads correctly (in the _Network_ tab). See if the styles appear in the _Style Editor_ tab